# Create hierarchy from row data

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, hierarchy, data-visualization

I am trying to create hierarchy for tree layout of d3.js but i have row data means only links and some of the links are really recursing with each other  like some times in link two different source have same target so by basic d3.js tree function it will get issue with that situations.

I there any other option for it ?

For Ex. I have data like this

```
{ source: "main1", target: "level 3"}  
{ source: "main2", target: "level 3"}
{ source: "level 3", target: "level 4"}
```

so this will be like this scenario

```
0     0
 \   /
   0
   |
   0
```

and also these are not under one root parent also means two different parents in tree !!!

Any helpful links will be appreciate

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that you have data representing an arbitrary directed graph (possibly acyclic?), and you want to create a hierarchy from it. As you point out, it does not represent a hierarchy. So what do you expect? I think the answer to your 'question' is:

***"You cannot do that. You will need to use a different visualization that does not require a hierarchy."***

Perhaps you want a DAG visualization like
https://github.com/nickholub/d3-dag-visualization

If you are convinced that you want a hierarchy, please supply a full set of example data ALONG WITH what you expect the result to be. We cannot guess what you want from what you have supplied.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is not possible with directly with d3.js  but there another ways do it with D3.js

1) Rather than using

```
tree.links(nodes);
```

For get links connected with each nodes we can use

```
d3.layout.hierarchy()
```

and override

```
.links(nodes)
```

method and manage links connections by our own means the original child will stay where you want to put it under it's multiple parent and by giving some unique id identify nodes and connect them .
Note : here if you are using some copy past code from example you need to change this code  where

```
  var link = svgGroup.selectAll("path.link")
        .data(links, function(d) {
            return d.target.id;
        });
```

because now it's not depends on child and parent all links are their own so give them id and use that id as filter rather than using target id

2) Or you can create own function by your self and create one array or object which holds  object just like link and just you need top give them source , target and link id  based on your connection logic. You can play with it whatever you want because it's your own you can add extra attr etc.